# Unit conversion with Bash

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script that converts units from a very specific input.

I started out doing simple read and echo statements and was able to get it to read a very specific input derived from declared integers and numbers but I'm having trouble getting it to work with if statements.

Here is my simple code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i n
in=inches
ft=feet

read number in "as" feet
if [ ]; then
    echo "$n $in = $[n/12] $ft"
fi
```

What I want to do now is to create if/else statements to flow according to a number of conditionals dependent on the user input. So I want the user to type something like "24 inches as feet" or "50 yards as inches" and execute its respective output. Right now, I don't really know what to put into the if statements without getting an error like "command not found".

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just a hint to get you started, use a pattern match: `[[ "$input" == *inches*as*feet* ]]` The [[...]] will treat the right side as a pattern (as in a file pattern) if you don't quote it. The first * will skip over the number, while the extra * characters will allow for minor variations such as extra spaces. (You might also want to look up the case statement which would be more compact for multiple matches.)

Comment: The fact that you are attempting this in Bash makes me cringe.  The string manipulation and parsing capabilities in Bash leave lots to be desired.  I recommend switching to a different language.  I would personally choose Perl.

Comment: Note that `bash` works with integers...there might also be a `units` program on your system to do this job.

Comment: For the more capable division part look into [bc](http://hacktux.com/bash/math)

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use quotes on the variables in your `read` command.

```
read number in as feet
```

Another improvement is to rename the variables to represent what they store. I'm going to replace `as` with the underscore, a valid but "unreadable" name that emphasizes that it's just a placeholder, and we don't really care about its value.

```
read value src_unit _ dest_unit
# If the user enters "24 inches as feet", we have:
#  value=24
#  src_unit=inches
#  _=as
#  dest_unit=feet
```

Now, your if statements need to check two things: what is the units of the value, and what unit do we want to convert it to. Here's a template:

```
if [ "$src_unit" = X ] && [ "$dest_unit" = Y ]; then
   # Convert X into Y
fi
```

You would replace `X` and `Y` with the units you are converting from and to, and
the code in the middle would be something like `new_value=$(( $value / 12 ))`, if
converting from inches to feet. Note that `bash` cannot handle floating-point arithmetic,
which is a topic for another question.

A `case` statement, as suggested by cwgem:

```
case "$src_unit-$dest_unit" in
    inches-feet)
      new_value=$(( $value / 12 ))
      ;;
    gallons-quarts)
      new_value=$(( $value * 4 ))
      ;;
    *)  echo "I don't know how to convert $src_unit to $dest_unit"
      ;;
esac
```

Comment: I'm thinking a case statement would work better, where you just concat `src_unit` and `dest_unit` together to have something like `case "${src_unit}-${dest_unit} in "inches-feet") things here;; esac`

Comment: Agreed. I was envisioning nested `if` statements (`if [ src = inches ]; then  # more if statements for conversion to feet, cm, etc; fi`), but a `case` statement would be a simpler way to start.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you guys. The case statement was the way to go. I'd rep you all if I could.

Answer (score 0):

## !/bin/bash

echo "enter a number to be converted"

read number

feet=$(($number*12))

inches=$(($number/12))

```
echo "feet conversion to inches="$feet

echo "inches conversion to feet="$inches
```

fi